# How to change maven's groupId in project already deployed on Nexus

Tags: maven, nexus

I've got many projects. All build by Maven and deployed on Nexus. Unfortunatelly, there's one big mess with maven's groupIds in that projects. I have to clean it up.

Here's my plan to relocate groupId in projects:
1. find all dependent projects
2. change groupId in the project
3. move artifacts tree on Nexus from old group to new one (including all files like `pom.xml`, `maven-metadata.xml`, `*.md5`, `*sha1`, etc)
4. change groupIds in dependent projects

Nexus and all projects are all internal, so there's no problem with finding dependent projects.

Should I modify files: `pom.xml` and `maven-metadata.xml`, stored with artifacts? I suppose I should change `groupId` in `maven-metadata.xml`. But are `pom.xml` files (stored next to each artifact) used somehow or they are just kept for information how that artifact was build?

Comment: Simple answer to this. Never. Only change the orignal GAV coordinates and make a new deployment to nexus and start using the new GAV coordinates in your other projects...keep the old location otherwise you will highly likely break other builds of which you don't know and furthermore break reproducibility. Apart from that if you would do that as you described you need to change the content of the already deployed pom files which will break also the checksums...So simply No!

Comment: I fully agree it shouldn't be a good habit. Also, I agree it should be strongly inadvisable if projects were public. But considering the facts:  1. both all projects and Nexus are internal and can find all dependent projects  2. in Maven documentation there's predicted neccessary of project's relocation (https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-relocation.html)  I think it's not impossible to make. All I need to know is: if Maven / Nexus use any information from `pom.xml` files stored next to artifacts.

Comment: And about checksums. If it's necessary, they can be generated again. It's not a problem. But I don't know any Nexus internal mechanism that uses them. Is there any? None of our tools use that checksums.

Comment: Why is the way which is described impossible? The pom defines groupId, artifactid, version which represent the folder location in Nexus folder structure...Furthermore It doesn't matter if all these artifacts are internal..I make a bet they will be used by others...Nexus does not use the checksums but Maven does...and will complain about wrong ones...

Comment: That's way I ask my question here. So I'll modify pom files (groupId correction) and later generate new checksums.